# C# Generic Type as parameter

Tags: c#, generics

I've got following interfaces and classes:

```
public abstract class A {}
public abstract class B<T> : IType<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
}

public interface IType<T>
{
    T Value { get; set; }
}

public class C : B<String>, IType<String> { }
public class D : B<Int32>, IType<Int32> { }
```

How can I pass C or D as a method parameter, without using `A`? 
So the parameter type has to be `IType<T>` or `B<T>`.

Unfortunatly I'm completly new to generics, so any help would be gratefully appreciated. Thanks!

**EDIT**

What I'm trying to achieve is something like the following (won't compile)

```
public void SetB(B<T> Type)
{
    //Do stuff...
}
```

So that I can pass C or D to that method.

Comment: What you have currently doesn't compile, so it is really hard to understand what you're trying to do.  Can you please update your question so that your code compiles, and then add a quick pseudocode snippet that explains what you are trying to do?

Comment: Since `B<T>` is `IType<T>`, being "`B<T>` or `IType<T>`" is equivalent to being `IType<T>`, so what is wrong with simply using `IType<T>` as your parameter type?

Comment: @DavidL Thank you, updated my question

Comment: @fuglede That is what I'm trying to do. Unfortunatly I cannot use IType<T> as a parameter Type

Comment: @Nordrassil your question says passing as a method parameter. Your question still doesn't say where you're trying to pass to.  What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: Please show an example of what you're trying to accomplish. It isn't altogether clear what you're trying to do that doesn't work/isn't allowed.

Comment: @Nordrassil Why can you not use `IType<T>` as a parameter? Can you use a generic method: `public void MyMethod<T>(IType<T> arg)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your method can also be [generic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-methods).

```
public void MyMethod<T>(IType<T> arg)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

You can call it like so.

```
MyMethod(new C());
MyMethod(new D());
```

Comment: Thank you! It was as simple as that :)

Comment: @Nordrassil: Note that you can also call `MyMethod<string>(new C())`.  You can elide the generic type arguments and the compiler will try to figure out what you meant from the arguments, but it cannot always do so successfully.

Comment: @EricLippert Thank you very much for the usefull hint!